# Moving a tab group into a tab group

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am working on making my own adaptive gui builder in matlab, and I stumbled across a really strange bug in matlab. I found that you cannot hide a `uipanel` that contains a `uitabgroup`, then move it into a separate `uitab`. Here's the shortest snippet I could create:

```
a = figure;
b = uipanel(a);
uitabgroup(b);
b.Visible = 'off';
e = uitabgroup(a);
f = uitab(e);
b.Parent = f;
b.Visible = 'on';
```

The weirdest part with this bug is that this works: (just removing the panel and moving the tab group.)

```
a = figure;
%b = uipanel(a);
%uitabgroup(b);
b = uitabgroup(a);
b.Visible = 'off';
e = uitabgroup(a);
e.Position = [.5,.5,.5,.5];
f = uitab(e);
b.Parent = f;
b.Visible = 'on';
```

In an attempt to exhaust all causes, this also works:

```
a = figure;
b = uitabgroup(a);
c = uitab(b);
d = uitabgroup(c);
e = uitab(d);
uipanel(e);
```

and this:

```
a = figure;
b = uitabgroup(a);
c = uitab(b);
D = uipanel(c);
d = uitabgroup(D);
e = uitab(d);
uipanel(e);
```

I was wondering if you could help me find the cause to this, and a possible fix. Just a word of warning, the first code snippet will completely crash matlab. Removing the `b.Visible` line(s) will let the snippet run like normal. Unfortunately each part of this is rather needed by me for my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself, but I would love to know why this occurs. To fix it simply set it as visible before changing parents and then resize it so:

```
a = figure;
b = uipanel(a);
uitabgroup(b);
b.Visible = 'off';
e = uitabgroup(a);
f = uitab(e);
b.Visible = 'on';
b.Parent = f;
b.Position = [0 0 1 1];
```